# Why am i allowed to pass an object of the bounding type of a generic type to a function, but not allowed to return it?

Tags: java, generics

When a generic static method is written like this:

```
public static <T extends SuperClass> T foo() {
    return new SupperClass();
}
```

, an incompatible types compilation error is thrown indicating that `SuperClass` cannot be converted to `T`.

On the other hand, when another generic static method is written like this:

```
public static <T extends SuperClass> void bar(T val) {
    // do something....
}
```

the code compiles just fine when the function is called using: `bar(new SuperClass())`.

Also the same thing happens when using a generic class with the bounded generic type as it's type parameter, 
whether it is the return type or a parameter of the function.

For example this causes the same compilation error to be thrown:

```
public static <T extends SupperClass> GenericClass<T> foo() {
    return new GenericClass<SuperClass>();
}
```

indicating that `GenericClass<SuperClass>` cannot be converted to `GenericClass<T>`.However, this:

```
public static <T extends SuperClass> void bar(GenericClass<T> val) {
    // do something....
}
```

compiles just fine when it is called using `bar(new GenericClass<SuperClass>)`.

So to sum up the question, why can a generic method whose formal type is bounded with some supertype, and takes a parameter of this formal type, be called with an object of the supertype, while it can't return an object of the supertype when the return type is specified as the formal type ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: because `SupperClass` is not a `T`. It *may* be, but for all subclasses of `SupperClass` returning an instance of the top class simply is not valid.

Comment: What do you think the difference is between `public static <T extends SuperClass> T foo()` and `public static SuperClass foo()`?

Comment: @shmosel: I guess they are the same but the former ensures type safety ?

Comment: Not at all. The former can be parameterized with a specific subtype of `SuperClass`.

Comment: @shmosel: I thought you are asking about their difference solely, regardless of how can they be modified. But what does this add up to the answer of my question ?

Comment: The point is `T` can represent `SubClass extends SuperClass`, in which case `new SuperClass()` is not a valid return value.

Comment: @shmosel: I see.But my problem is that you can call the function with an object of the `SuperClass` type if it is parameterized with `T`, and my question is that how it can work when calling with a `SuperClass` object, but not when returning one.

Comment: Because it's the *caller* who gets to decide what `T` is. Not the method.

Comment: @shmosel: Oh so it's because `T` is defined with the argument type if the function is parameterized with `T`, but if it is not, `T` won't be defined and the problem arises from here.I got it now thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiler is looking at the static type when doing compilation. 
When you're trying to return a

`new SupperClass()`

object - the compiler must be sure that the static types are matched - and is doing so by converting from **SupperClass** to **T**.

When you'll do this casting yourself:

```
 (T) new SupperClass()
```

it will give you a warning on unchecked cast - because technically you can program it but its successfulness depends on runtime types...

When you're returning void - you're returning nothing - so no casting needs to be done.

A comment on casting: casting up will always succeed (you can always loose information) casting down - depends on the dynamic type and not always succeed.

Comment: But why does the compiler need to cast anything if `<T extends SuperClass>` stands for (subtypes of `SuperClass` including `SuperClass` itself) ? then `T` would stand for `SuperClass` and no casting would be needed.

Comment: Well, think about that - when this T is being defined?
When the generic type is an argument the T is defined when you're sending this argument.
In this case - the T is defined when you'll place the result of the function:
A a = foo(); // T = A
D d = foo(); // T = D
In the first line the compiler expects static type A and in the second type D. 
If A and D are extending other Class B - than this cast won't work!
You can't return A from the function, and then try to place it into D - although both of them are subtypes of B

Comment: Yup thanks for the clarification. I had to know that `T` wouldn't actually 
be defined when the function isn't parameterized with it, so the compiler can't decide what cast to use.I got it now Thanks.